# Where does Mozilla host their XUL XSD Schema?

Tags: xsd, xul, dtd

I'm trying to find the official schema (XSD or DTD) for [Mozilla XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL).

Nothing except [this weird link](http://mozilla.doslash.org/xulschema/) crop up in Google searches.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link : http://www.ohloh.net/p/xulschema

It's good for you ?

**EDIT :** More links

[Official Mozilla Dev page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Using_Visual_Studio_as_your_XUL_IDE) which brings to [this site](http://xulschema.codeplex.com/) with XSD file

Comment: Thanks @Adrien Lacroix (+1) - I love it! Just one concern here: why is it hosted on ohloh and not a part of the Mozilla project? I'm wondering if this is a 3rd party *guess* at what the XUL Schema is, but not officially endorsed/supported by Mozilla...if that's the case, I'll certainly take it if nothing else is available, but would *prefer* something that Mozilla maintains themselves. Thanks again!

Comment: I will continue my searches and I will keep you in touch ;)

Comment: Okay @IAmYourFaja, so I found another links :
[Official Mozilla Dev page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Using_Visual_Studio_as_your_XUL_IDE) which brings to [this site](http://xulschema.codeplex.com/) with XSD file

Comment: This is great for autocompletion and such, but keep in mind that it's not the "real" DTD ;)

Comment: The links are dead! :-(

Comment: @einpoklumn Seems that [Mozilla has deprecated XUL](https://www.zdnet.com/home-and-office/networking/mozilla-changes-firefox-apis-developers-unhappy/) since 2015. Don't know if it's still relevant 8 years later. The new standard for Mozilla Addons are [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

Answer (score 1):

There is no DTD because any valid XML document is valid XUL: you can [define custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/Custom_XUL_Elements_with_XBL)  with XBL.